# Passing data from a django view to a template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I would like to display data from a view after a calculation to a template. The View collects data from a Django form and then performs a simple calculation. However, the function does not redirect to the template.

```
 views.py

    from . import forms
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

    def index(request):
        form = forms.InputForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})


    def addition(a,b):
        c = a + b
        return c


    def input_form_Addition(request):
        if request.method == 'post':
           form = forms.InputForm(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
              input1 = form.cleaned_data['input1']
              input2 = form.cleaned_data['input2']
              total = addition(input1,input2)

              return render(request, 'output.html', {'total': total})
        else:
             form = forms.InputForm()
```

The template (output.html) looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Forms</title>

    </head>
    <body>

      <p>The Sum is {{ total }}</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

My url routing is as follows:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import index
    from simple_addition import views

      urlpatterns = [
           path('', views.index, name='index'),
           path('output/', views.input_form_Addition, name='output')
             ]
```

My Django form displays well and looks as follows.

forms.py
        from django import forms

```
    class InputForm(forms.Form):
       input1 = forms.FloatField()
       input2 = forms.FloatField()
```

And is displayed at:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Forms</title>

   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Addition Page</h2>
      <p>Fill in two numbers to get their sum</p>

      <form method="post">
           {% csrf_token %}
           {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Add" >
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `redirect` doesn't accept a template. That's now how redirection works. In simple terms, redirection means that you're redirecting your user to another url. Instead, just use the `render` function.

Comment: The `render` function also does not display the _output.hml_ . Instead the  _input form_ is reloaded once again.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your view.

Comment: I have fixed the identation and the replaced the render function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you put you form code ? (template and forms.py)

edit:

Ok i find your problem :

```
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Add" >
```

You miss a action for post form :

forms template :

```
<form method="post" action="/output/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Add" >
</form>
```

urls.py

```
path('output/', views.input_form_Addition, name='output')
```

views.py

```
from . import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

def index(request):
    form = forms.InputForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})


def addition(a,b):
    c = a + b
    return c


def input_form_Addition(request):
    form = forms.InputForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        input1 = form.cleaned_data['input1']
        input2 = form.cleaned_data['input2']
        total = addition(input1, input2)

        return render(request, 'output.html', {'total': total})
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Can't add comment with my reputation i'm new

Comment: I have added the form action. The `output.html` is displayed, however, it does not give the total variable from the view.

Comment: Can you send a result return on your view ?

Comment: Sorry ... I didn't understand that.

Comment: You say "it does not give the total variable from the view". what does your view show? and what do you want to display on this view normally

Comment: Oh. `output.html` is not giving the total after injecting it      
      <p>The Sum is {{ total }}</p>

Comment: I edit my code with all view you nedd for work. i test it and injecting <p>The Sum is {{ total }}</p> works

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the line in functions ***input_form_Addition(request):***

```
if request.method == 'post':
```

with

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```